# InvalidStateError with msSaveBlob for json file in IE

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer, download, blob

I have some problems to implement a solution to by-pass the missing behaviour of "download" attribute in Internet Explorer.

Users can download three types of files :

- CSV
- geoJSON
- KML

So no problem in Chrome and FF. It works like this :

```
var tempCSV = json2CSV(geojson);
var csv = "text/csv;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(tempCSV);
$('#downloadCSV').attr('href', "data:" + csv);
```

As IE is not doing things like everyone else, I use [msSaveBlob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh779016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to deal with it like this :

```
if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
   var blobCSV = new Blob([tempCSV]);
   $('#downloadCSV').click(function (e) {
       navigator.msSaveBlob(blobCSV, "geo.csv");
       e.preventDefault();
});
```

It works correctly for CSV and KML files.
But not with geoJSON. I get an error with this line :

```
var blobGeoJSON = new Blob([tempGeoJSON]);
```

And I get this error : "InvalidStateError"

From where problem could come ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally after reading again my code, I found the problem.

You have to stringify your json before create a blob with it, like this :

```
var tempGeoJSON = JSON.stringify(geojson);
```

Instead of this :

```
var tempGeoJSON = geojson;
```